# Use Sharepoint as Source for QnA Maker

Tags: sharepoint, botframework, azure-qna-maker

If I understood well the link you can provide as input for a data source for the QnA maker has to be a ‘public’ one. This means that you can’t have a link to for example a folder on Sharepoint (or even a file on Sharepoint)? So what do I do in that case if I want to make a knowledge base based on lots of information on Sharepoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the the documentation on QnAMaker, they currently do not support authenticated data sources, such as those on SharePoint. The only way to use documents from SharePoint as knowledge-base data is to download the files manually from SharePoint, and then use QnAMaker's file-upload option to extract the question-answer pairs.

Bear in mind, the files must be in the supported format of .tsv, .pdf, .doc, .docx, or .xlsx. Also, as you've stated 'lots of information', QnAMaker does limit how many  documents you can add to the free tier: 3 documents, up to 1MB per. The standard tier, which is $10/month, allows for unlimited documents.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot ! Do you know whether this is on the product roadmap to make authenticated data sources possible?

Comment: @Anne it looks like [secured SharePoint data sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/add-sharepoint-datasources) are now supported.

Answer (score 0):

i had a project where i have to publish qna pairs from sharepoint to the qna maker. what i did was to create an SPFX application and a web service that had to call the endpoints of the QnAMaker (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/quickstarts/csharp)

it was a bit of a hassle though since updating a qna maker item needs to have a specific string, one wrong syntax and it will cause an error.